# Can the get of a property be abstract and the set be virtual?

Tags: c#, properties

I have a base class like this:

```
public class Trajectory{
    public int Count { get; set; }
    public double Initial { get; set { Count = 1; } }
    public double Current { get; set { Count ++ ; } }
}
```

So, I have code in the base class, which makes the set-s virtual, but the get-s must stay abstract. So I need something like this:

```
...
public double Initial { abstract get; virtual set { Count = 1; } }
...
```

But this code gives an error.
The whole point is to implement the counter functionality in the base class instead in all the derived classes.
So, how can I make the get and set of a property with different modifiers?

Comment: Maybe you should write separate GetInitial SetInitial methods...

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding the intention behind your code.  It's extremely unusual to have a setter for a property that ignores the input value being set.  If you change this to use methods (with no unused input value to confuse things), there's no more need for an abstract get / virtual set.

Comment: The point of a setter is that it "sets" (in some way) the value inputted. The way you implement your set, it is more a method.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

split it into 2 functions:

```
public double Initial
{
    get { return GetInitial(); }
    set { SetInitial(value); }
}

protected virtual void SetInitial(double value)
{
    Count = 1;
}

protected abstract double GetInitial();
```

Answer (score 1):

Make it neither abstract nor virtual.  And make the backing field private.  That way, a derived class cannot override it nor can it mess with it.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. At least I haven't found a solution.

If property is marked as `abstract` then neither it's getter and setter can have bodies.